# Is it safe to query Django ORM directly with the user input?

Tags: python, django, security, django-rest-framework, sanitization

Hi I am manually implementing an API filter where user can filter the database,

one of a query would look like this,

`book/?writer=Anonymous` where the writer is passed by a GET request from a HTML form (not Django form).

the lookup method is,

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.GET.dict():
        keys = request.GET.dict()

        if 'writer' in keys:
            queryset = Book.objects.filter(writer__name__contains=keys['writer'])
            # serialize queryset if queryset non empty else return HTTP404
            # process and return serializer data
```

my question is, **is it safe to query the ORM directly with user input?**

if not, what should be done before querying?

I am using a minimal Django Rest Framework installation with no filter support (for some strange reasons)

thank you.

Comment: Do you plan on allowing `book/?User=Admin`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection

Comment: @Sayse no the `filter()` arguments are limited to `['writer', 'language', 'category', 'price']` etc.. not with users. My concern is that if unsanitized code is insecure.

Comment: It would probably be a better idea to provide a rest api, as well as safer, your users would find it less confusing

Comment: aint it a Rest API? Its for an single page app. I believe its a rest api! why did you said so?

Comment: A REST api would be /book/writer/Anonymous. Not that I necessarily agree with Sayse; I think query params are fine for search queries like this. But to answer your question, yes this is safe.

Answer (score 4):

From the docs

"Django’s querysets are protected from SQL injection since their queries are constructed using query parameterization. A query’s SQL code is defined separately from the query’s parameters. Since parameters may be user-provided and therefore unsafe, they are escaped by the underlying database driver."